# Laravel: Using multiple columns for authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

I have a Laravel 6 application.

In a typical application, the user would just specify their `email`, where the email is unique.

However, in my application, I have 2 columns in the User model that is used to authenticate users.

- `app_id`
- `email`
- `unique(app_id, email)`

So in order to login, we need to pass both an `app_id` and an `email`, along with the `password`. The same `email` could be used across different `app_id`s.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: have you checked the authentication docs for manually authenticating the user? that combined with looking into the LoginController should be all you need

Comment: The issue is that I can only find customising a single column. Not querying across columns.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users   it tells you how to do this .. once you know how `attempt` works you can adjust specific methods of the  LoginController to adjust the credentials and the validation as needed ... if you are not using the LoginController then you have what you need for the most part

Answer (score 2):

The default login actions provided by `Auth::routes()` are the following:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

This is the default `login` function, part of the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait used by the `LoginController`:

```
    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
            $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

There are a few ways to approach this.

#### Option 1: Override `login` function in `LoginController`

```
# app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // add more stuff like validation, return the view you want, etc.
        // This is barebones
        auth()->attempt($request->only(['app_id', 'login', 'password']);
    }
```

#### Option 2: Override both the `validateLogin` and the `credentials` functions in `LoginController`

```
# app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'app_id' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('app_id', 'email', 'password');
    }
```