# Laravel: Using multiple columns for authentication in passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-passport, laravel-authentication

*Note: I have asked a similar question here: [Laravel: Using multiple columns for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077680/laravel-using-multiple-columns-for-authentication) but this question is referring specifically to Passport*.

I have a Laravel 6 application that uses **Passport**.

In a typical application, the user would just specify their email, where the email is unique.

However, in my application, I have 2 columns in the User model that is used to authenticate users.

- app_id (usually sent as a header)
- email
- unique(app_id, email)

So in order to login, we need to pass both an app_id and an email, along with the password. The same email could be used across different app_ids.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: same  issue here.. anyone pls, help .